# input value in email subject - php mailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I want the value of the name field to appear in the mail subject from the user of my site. I'm using the phpmailer plugin. 
Currently, "Message from the user" is displayed.

handler.php:

```
$pp = new FormHandler(); 

$validator = $pp->getValidator();
$validator->fields(['name','email'])->areRequired()->maxLength(50);
$validator->field('email')->isEmail();
$validator->field('message')->maxLength(6000);
$validator->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

FormHandler.php:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->emails = array();
    $this->validator = FormValidator::create();
    $this->mailer = new PHPMailer;
    $this->mail_template='';

    $this->mailer->Subject = "Message from the user";

    $host = isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])?$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']:'localhost';
    $from_email ='forms@'.$host;
    $this->mailer->setFrom($from_email,'BanerBunny.pl',false);

    $this->captcha = false;   

    $this->attachments = [];

    $this->recaptcha =null;
}
```

and html:

```
<div id="form-main">
   <div id="form-div">
      <form class="montform" id="reused_form" enctype=&quot;multipart/form-data&quot;>
         <p class="name">
            <input name="name" type="text" class="feedback-input" placeholder="Imię i Nazwisko"
                   id="name" required/>
         </p>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain how form submits to the code? You do not have `action` attribute on form.How `FormHandler.php` and `handler.php` linked. And did you try passing `$this->mailer->Subject = $validator->field('name')`

Comment: The form submits the code through JQuery/AJAX Yes, I tried to use this variable: $ this-> mailer-> Subject = $ validator-> field ('name'). Unfortunately, the form does not send out at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Instead** of:

```
$this->mailer->Subject = "Message from the user";
```

**Try** to use:

```
$this->mailer->Subject = ($_POST['name']);
```

It should work fine.

Answer (score -1):

The form submits the code through JQuery/AJAX 
Yes, I tried to use this variable: $ this-> mailer-> Subject = $ validator-> field ('name'). Unfortunately, the form does not send out at all.

form.js

```
$(function () {
function after_form_submitted(data) {
    if (data.result == 'success') {
        $('form#reused_form').hide();
        $('#success_message').css('display', 'flex');
        $('#error_message').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('#error_message').append('<ul></ul>');

        jQuery.each(data.errors, function (key, val) {
            $('#error_message ul').append('<li>' + key + ':' + val + '</li>');
        });
        $('#success_message').hide();
        $('#error_message').show();

        //reverse the response on the button
        $('button[type="button"]', $form).each(function () {
            $btn = $(this);
            label = $btn.prop('orig_label');
            if (label) {
                $btn.prop('type', 'submit');
                $btn.text(label);
                $btn.prop('orig_label', '');
            }
        });

    }//else
}

$('#reused_form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $form = $(this);
    //show some response on the button
    $('button[type="submit"]', $form).each(function () {
        $btn = $(this);
        $btn.prop('type', 'button');
        $btn.prop('orig_label', $btn.text());
        $btn.text('Wysyłanie ...');
    });


    var formdata = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'handler.php',
        data: formdata,
        success: after_form_submitted,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false
    });

});
```

Comment: post a comment to your question or edit your question to make it more clear but do not add an answer just to reply to another comment